ERROR try-runtime::cli] ❌ Weight safety issues detected
Hi I am trying to run try-runtime to verify runtime upgrade but getting below error after migration is executed.
storage updated to v2! Migrated 124247 clouds ✅
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4485438Z [2024-07-20T13:41:16Z INFO  try_runtime_core::commands::on_runtime_upgrade] ℹ Skipping idempotency check
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4486438Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] PoV size (zstd-compressed compact proof): 5.9 MB. For parachains, it's your responsibility to verify that a PoV of this size fits within any relaychain constraints.
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4487132Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z WARN  try-runtime::cli] A PoV size of 5.9 MB is significant. Most relay chains usually accept PoVs up to 5.0 MB. Proceed with caution.
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4487542Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z INFO  try-runtime::cli] Consumed ref_time: 16.531025s (826.55% of max 2s)
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4488448Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z WARN  try-runtime::cli] Consumed ref_time is >= 80% of the max allowed ref_time. Please ensure the migration is not be too computationally expensive to be fit in a single block.
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4488807Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z ERROR try-runtime::cli] ❌ Weight safety issues detected.
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4489310Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z ERROR try_runtime_core::common::misc_logging] ------------------------------------------------
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4489463Z     
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4489542Z     
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4490086Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z ERROR try_runtime_core::common::misc_logging] ❌ Issues detected, exiting non-zero. See logs.
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4490162Z     
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4490238Z     
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4490728Z [2024-07-20T13:41:17Z ERROR try_runtime_core::common::misc_logging] ------------------------------------------------
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4490869Z     
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4490952Z     
2024-07-20T13:41:19.4494308Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.

After installing try-runtime-cli, I am verifying runtime upgrade against a live environment using below commands:
try-runtime --runtime ./target/release/wbuild/dev-runtime/dev_runtime.compact.compressed.wasm \
          on-runtime-upgrade --disable-idempotency-checks live --uri wss://<liveURL>

I couldn't find way to fix it. Can someone please help me to fix this?

Your migration is doing too much stuff in one go and would stall the chain - for at last 16 seconds. This is pretty bad for a parachain, but for a Solo/Relay it can still be acceptable. Note that there could also be an attacker front-running your migrations to make it even slower.
Either way, using a Multi-Block-Migration (MBM) is a better way. It is still a quite new feature, but was used by Ajuna network successfully already. Docs are here.
disable-idempotency-checks is also dangerous. Migrations should always be idempotent. We had issues with chain-stalls on Rococo and Westend multiple times because of this not being the case. I would be very careful with this option.
We have a specific VersionedMigration wrapper to make it easy to create idempotent migrations.

Hey,
I am running solo chain with version V1.1.0 so it does not have multi-block migration capabilities however I tried to follow same approach which pallet-contracts does BUT still facing same issue. Is there any other way to fix it?

You can ignore the weight warning on a solo chain.

As mentioned, your runtime upgrade migration may be too extensive.
Take our chain as an example; we also have a significant migration with over a thousand items in storage. We have decided to remove 100 items with each runtime upgrade. This may not be the ideal solution for you, especially since we have multi-block migration capabilities in the latest Substrate version. However, I just want to emphasize that you can divide your large migration into several smaller migrations.

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/6bb4ab8bbf265966183427cd61cb34b30d29369d/runtime/darwinia/src/migration.rs#L63


Hey,
I am running solo chain with version V1.1.0 so it does not have multi-block migration capabilities however I tried to follow same approach which pallet-contracts does BUT still facing same issue. Is there any other way to fix it?

Check this https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-common/pull/1234/files
We remove 500 items every block.
